# Forecasting weather with time-dependent regression model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I am interested in making a time-dependent prediction model. The set up looks something like this:

Given weather data from the days Monday-Saturday I would like to predict the high point on Sunday. Now, this unfeasible since we only have a small number of data points. But I do have Mon-Sat weather data from $M$ different locations, say in California, where $M>300,000$. Part from the feature set includes location data. So I would like my model to have as input Mon-Sat weather data from any location in California, for example, Santa Monica, and as output a prediction of the high point. Given that I have $M$ locations to train on, I would like a model that takes into account areas that are similar to Santa Monica (other beaches and locations that are within a certain radius of Santa Monica) and ignores other locations like mountain/inland areas.

I have been searching for a model that fits this description but I haven't stumbled upon anything. Or does this training method simply not make sense? I have never done any time dependent models, so I wouldn't know how feasible this problem is. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description "I would like a model that takes into account areas that are similar to Santa Monica ... and ignores other locations" is a good summary of the **[k-NN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm)** family of approaches.

In the context of meteorology, relationships between climate at different locations are known as [teleconnections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleconnection) (e.g. [EOF maps](https://www.r-bloggers.com/reot-empirical-orthogonal-teleconnections-in-r/)).

However your problem also has a shorter-term weather component. For example "time dependent" would include things like [advection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection#Meteorology) of [pressure systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_system). Weather forecasting incorporates these effects in great detail via sophisticated [physics-based models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_weather_prediction) that assimilate data using techniques such as [Ensemble Kalman filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_Kalman_filter).

Probably this is more than you would need, but simpler approaches could be possible. For example, advection could induce time-lagged correlations between nearby locations. However which locations are (tele-)connected, and the sign of the lag, would depend on which way the wind is blowing (i.e. the [upwind](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19618/why-are-upwind-schemes-stable-in-convection-flow-calculation) direction). Now if you have a west-coast US location, and no data over the Pacific, this may be less relevant (given common [circulation patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_stream)).